# getting the higher value out of two tensors elementwise in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have 2 2d tensors of the same size (let's say shape =[80,90]).
I want to get the value of the variable whose absolute value is bigger elementwise.

In python I would do something like this:

`mask = np.abs(a)>np.abs(b)`

`c = a*mask + b*~mask`

How do I do this in tensorflow while still being able to calculate gradients?

I know I can do this:

`mask = tf.abs(a) > tf.abs(b)`

but then:

`c= tf.cast(mask, tf.float32) *  a + tf.cast(~mask, tf.float32) * b`

doesn't pass gradients as the cast operation doesn't pass gradients.

Answer (score 2):

Use np.maximum:

```
np.maximum(a, b, where=abs(a) > abs(b))
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I described; I want the to choose from a, b (not abs(a), abs(b)) using the maximum between abs(a), abs(b)

Answer (score 1):

@coldspped answers work fine. But if you want a general purpose method that can extract element based on a random mask, you can use [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) api. For your problem, the answer is as following:

```
mask = tf.abs(a) - tf.abs(b)
c = tf.where(mask, a, b)
```